# Impact of td/th background over table border

Tags: html, css

I have a table element with a border:

```
.summary-table {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 115%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(195, 195, 195) !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When i use background color on thead tr it works fine

```
.summary-table thead tr{
    background-color: #E8E8E8 !important;
}
```

[image]

But when i use background color on thead th i get this (no border-top and left ):

```
.summary-table th {
    background-color: #E8E8E8 !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

[image]

Can anyone tell nme why i get this?

Comment: Your over-use of `!important` suggests that you're fighting another stylesheet. I'm not sure if that may influence any potential answers to this.

Comment: In that case you can probably drop the `!important` declarations.

Comment: nothing change when i drop it

Comment: I copy/past Your code in fiddle and look ok, borders are present (FF39) : https://jsfiddle.net/31et6bf3/1/

Comment: tested on chrome, opera and safari, too.

Comment: you think the problem from IE?